# Troubleshoot: Copy Data from multiple sheets into a single sheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which currently works, but does not display the way I want it to. I am new to VBA so I used this template from the web.

It makes a sheet called "Archive" then prints all the data I have in 40 other sheets onto it. The problem is that it from reads top to bottom.

```
Public Sub m()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim shArc As Worksheet
    Set shArc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive")
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case sh.Name
            Case Is <> "Archive"
                lRow = shArc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                sh.Range("B1:M247").Copy 
                _Destination:=shArc.Range("A" & lRow)
        End Select
    Next
    Set shArc = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want the macro to paste the data so that it is read from from left to right.

TLDR: code gathers data but pastes it all vertically. I want it to paste horizontally. can anyone alter it?

Comment: I proposed an edit that removed the `<br />` and added code formatting to make your post more readable. Please double check that I didn't accidently delete a character around these two lines: `sh.Range("B1:M247").Copy` and `_Destination:=shArc.Range("A" & lRow)` 
  
 Correct if needed.

Comment: So i tried editing the code with one of the replies here - it was in the correct orientation, but it only took the first column from each sheet. Each of the sheets I have 13 columns though.

Comment: I was just trying to edit to make the question more readable. Want to make sure I didn't add an error in the code block.

Answer (score 1):

So i tried messing around some more and edited one of the earlier replies. This seems to work for my purposes at the moment

```
Public Sub m()
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim shArc As Worksheet
    Set shArc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Archive")
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case sh.Name
             'do nothing
        Case Else
            lCol = shArc.Cells(1, shArc.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            sh.Range("B1:M247").Copy _
              Destination:=shArc.Cells(1, lCol + 13)
    End Select
Next
    Set shArc = Nothing
    Set sh = Nothing
End Sub
```